# Each image less than the previous JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with simple script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastHeight = 0;
    $("img").each(function(i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            $(this).css({
                height: lastHeight / 100 * 90
            })
        }
        lastHeight = parseInt($(this).css("height"));
    })
});
```

It's should show images where each image less than the previous (in % ratio).
But i have problem. In first time (no cache), i get one normal-sized image, and other images very small. If i reload page (using cache), it's working correctly.

Images loading by php:

```
foreach($top_images as $top_i) {
    echo '#'.$ratio;
    echo '
        <br><img class="top" src="'.$top_i['url'].'" ><br>
    ';
    $ratio++;
}
```

Comment: wait for the images to load... i..e. `$(document).ready(function() { ... your code });`

Comment: what if you wait for the document to be fully loaded?

Comment: Add some `console.log` calls  to figure you if you're getting the correct height for each image. If you're getting 0 for a height, your problem is surely that you have to wait for image's load event

Comment: This works fine http://jsfiddle.net/xhc073hf/1/ You should try to reproduce your problem in a small self contained example, like the one I just posted

Comment: @JuanMendes
Without cache it outputs:
0 24 
1 22 
2 20 
3 18 
4 16 
5 19 
I tried use name of class instead "img", but no result.

Comment: @WaffRider Did you try my example? That shows that it does work and there's something else breaking whatever you're doing. Again, you should isolate your code, remove everything else from the page to see if it works, then add one piece back at a time to find the code that is breaking your page.

Comment: @JuanMendes Sorry for that late answer.
http://pastebin.com/zbahehZ8 - i'm using this code. 
In firefox if i press ctrl+F5 i get small images.
If you add alert() in the end of function maybe it add understanding why this happend.
Alsough you can use <img class="top" src = "http://placehold.it/100x100" /> instead foreach construction and got same result

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're running the script before the images have fully loaded.

Image dimensions are only available after the images have finished loading.

Try to wrap the code in the [jquery ready method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastHeight = 0;
    $("img").each(function(i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            $(this).css({
                height: lastHeight / 100 * 90
            })
        }
        lastHeight = parseInt($(this).css('height'));
    })
});
```

Comment: @WaffRider Note that if the images are being loaded dynamically, you may have to wait for the image's load event, and be careful that they may already be cached

Comment: Are you loading the images dynamically? As @juanMendes suggests, you might need to work with the load event fired from the images instead.

Comment: @beije, no i load images not dinamically